# How to find precision @ N using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, precision, aggregation

I'd like to calculate the proportion of A grades of systems but only include questions with a certain number of grades. I start with the following data

```
system     question    grade
Sys1       Is?         A
Sys1       Is?         A
Sys1       Is?         C
Sys1       How?        B
Sys1       How?        A
Sys1       How?        F
Sys1       How?        F
Sys2       Is?         A
Sys2       Is?         A
Sys2       Is?         B
Sys2       How?        A
```

Precision = The proportion of A grades

N = Question has at least N grades in the system

I want to calculate the precision @ n for each system. For example, *Precision @ 2* would be the proportion of 'A' grades for each system for questions with at least 2 grades

I'm struggling to bring calculations together as I'm just learning Pandas. Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve using N=2:

1. Group by system, question and filter out groups with size < 2

```
    size = df.groupby('system', 'question').size()
    size[size >= 2]
    system  question
    Sys1    Is?    3
            How?   4
    Sys2    Is?    3
```

2. Get size (count) of each grade per system

   ```
   df.groupby(['system', 'question', 'grade']).size()
   system    question    grade
   Sys1      Is?         A     2
                         C     1
             How?        A     1
                         B     1
                         F     2
   Sys2     Is?          A     2
                         B     1
            How?         A     1
   ```
3. Join the groups, only keeping the questions that weren't filtered out in step 1

   `???`
4. Sum up all the A's per system and divide by the total number of grades in the system

   `???`

Desired result:

```
system   precision
Sys1         0.43
Sys2         0.66
```

Sys1 has a precision of 0.42 since it had 3 A's out of 7 grades. "Sys2 How?" is not included because it had less than 2 grades (N=1) so Sys2 has 2 A's out of the 3 grades for "Is?"

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'system':['Sys1', 'Sys1', 'Sys1', 'Sys1', 'Sys1', 'Sys1', 'Sys1', 'Sys2', 'Sys2', 'Sys2', 'Sys2'],
               'question': ['Is?', 'Is?', 'Is?', 'How?', 'How?', 'How?', 'How?', 'Is?', 'Is?', 'Is?', 'How?'],
               'grade': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'F', 'F', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A']})

q_size_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['system', 'question']).size(), columns=['q_size']).reset_index()

df2 = df.merge(q_size_df)

df2[df2['q_size']>=2].groupby(['system']).apply(lambda x: len(x[x['grade']=='A']) / len(x))
```

Output is:

```
system
Sys1    0.428571
Sys2    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

The idea behind it is to first calculate the size metric in question, then merge that metric back to the original df, and finally calculate your statistic on a filtered df. The advantage of doing it this way is that more filtering columns (i.e. criteria) can be added in the future without having to implement additional logic outside of the filtering column itself.

Comment: Very nice solution. It took me a bit to break down what was done but it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Generate the boolean mask:

```
mask = df.groupby(['system', 'question']).size().ge(2)
mask

system  question
Sys1    How?         True
        Is?          True
Sys2    How?        False
        Is?          True
dtype: bool
```

Perform `groupby` + `size` + `unstack` and fill `NaNs` with 0's.

```
A = df.groupby(['system', 'question', 'grade']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
A
```

[image]

Subset based on the mask:

```
B = A[mask]
B
```

[image]

`groupby` w.r.t first index axis and compute sum:

```
C = B.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Take column, *A* and divide by `DF's` sum across columns:

```
C['A']/C.sum(1)

system
Sys1    0.428571
Sys2    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

To output a `DF` instead with decimal rounding upto 2 places:

```
pd.DataFrame(C['A']/C.sum(1), columns=['precision']).round(2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution. I have not used unstack so I'm glad you've exposed that to me!

Comment: You're welcome by the way. Just wanted to show you in simple steps so that you can compare the boolean values of the series and the `DF` simultaneously with the help of `unstack` method.